# Is there a way to resize tray icons in Cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon

Skype for linux's icon is about 1.5x the size it should be and as a result is driving me insane.

Is there a way to resize the tray appearance of just that icon?

Answer (score 6):

System Settings>Panel>(Panel Appearance) Right Zone>Symbolic Icon Size + - as desired will change the size of all the icons in system tray portion of panel. Give it a couple seconds to change. There is also an option in drop down next to colored icon size scale to panel size optimally or scale to panel size exactly. That seems to make all icons in systray the same size.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: This does not change the size of all icons in there, but only some. E.g. for me, it resizes KDEConnect and Redshift, but doesn’t change the wifi, audio and battery icons.

Answer (score 1):

The Cinnamon panel "tray icons" are not all of the same type. The ones that look bigger are on the same applet. If right-click on the panel and set to edit panel mode, applets can be moved around on the panel, and Skype, Pidgin and Updates icons are moved together with their applet.

[~s o u r c e~ : Fix size of system tray icons in cinnamon](http://www.gregfreeman.org/2013/fix-size-of-system-tray-icons-in-cinnamon/)

Open `/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/systray@cinnamon.org/applet.js`; in Terminal:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/cinnamon/applets/systray@cinnamon.org/applet.js
```

and find the line that starts with:

```
const ICON_SCALE_FACTOR =
```

Change that, test to see which number fits your needs. (88 is big, 64 may be ok, I like 56) .

To see the changes ALT-F4 and type `r` then ENTER to restart the  Cinnamon desktop.

It works fine for Skype, Pidgin and Update icons.

Comment: Today default icon size on non-scaled panel is `1.0`, ICON_SCALE_FACTOR is `0.8`. Set ICON_SCALE_FACTOR to `1.0` to get same size on scaled panel.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps replacing the icon with something the correct size... Download a .png icon file that you would like to use and copy it to the respective `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/` directory. This will contain the following directories (which are the dimensions of the icons) : 16x16/apps/ 32x32/apps/ 48x48/apps/

If you download a 16x16 icon and call it newSkype.png

Get the newSkype.png file and copy it to `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps`, you can do that through either the GUI or terminal.

From there you would need do the following in a terminal (you may need sudo to copy this over):

```
cp /usr/share/applications/pidgin.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Next edit the skype.desktop file:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

Look for the line that says:

```
Icon=skype
```

This will need to change to the new icon name without the .png prefix...

```
Icon=newSkype
```

Save your changes... Then logout and log back in, hopefully something like that should work for you.

Comment: This will change Skype's icon in the "dock" or whatever you wanna call it. I was referring to the system tray (unless I'm missing something here?)

Comment: I'm not 100% on this as I am not in front of my machine at home to test but I thought with this method all references for the icon to the application throughout the desktop would now appear with the new icon, not just the dock...

Comment: I must have messed something up, I'll try again